# Lua: replace a substring

Tags: lua, substring, lua-patterns

I have something like

```
str = "What a wonderful string //011// this is"
```

I have to replace the `//011//` with something like `convertToRoman(011)` and then get

```
str = "What a wonderful string XI this is"
```

However, the conversion into roman numbers is no problem here. 
It is also possible that the string `str` didn't has a `//...//`. In this case it should simply return the same string.

```
function convertSTR(str)
  if not string.find(str,"//") then 
    return str 
  else 
    replace //...// with convertToRoman(...)
  end
  return str
end
```

I know that I can use `string.find` to get the complete `\\...\\` sequence. Is there an easier solution with pattern matching or something similiar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.gsub` accepts a function as a replacement. So, this should work

```
new = str:gsub("//(.-)//", convertToRoman)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like LPEG, therefore here is a solution with LPEG:

```
local lpeg = require"lpeg"
local C, Ct, P, R = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R

local convert = function(x)
    return "ROMAN"
end

local slashed = P"//" * (R("09")^1 / convert) * P"//"
local other = C((1 - slashed)^0)
local grammar =  Ct(other * (slashed * other)^0)

print(table.concat(grammar:match("What a wonderful string //011// this is"),""))
```